# UISearchBar in iPhone/iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have data like this...(All the data comes from .plist file...)

```
Searching Array - (
            {
            FirstName = "Ramesh";
            LastName = "Bean";
            EmpCode = 1001;
        },
            {
            FirstName = "Rohan";
            LastName = "Rathor";
            EmpCode = 102;
        },
            {
            FirstName = "Priya";
            LastName = "Malhotra";
            EmpCode = 103;
        },
            {
            FirstName = "Mukesh";
            LastName = "Sen";
            EmpCode = 104;
        },
            {
            FirstName = "Priya";
            LastName = "Datta";
            EmpCode = 105;
        }

    )
```

I want implement search data from this array on the basis of FirstName (key).

I am able to search data with the "FirstName(Key)"

but after filtering data suppose i clicked Row( in the data) which is displayed in the TableView. It Navigate me to New-Controller with all the information of that particular employee (like: FirstName,LastName,EmpCode).

How can i get information?

As i gone through the search sample codes.

Here is my search code...

```
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger TotalNoOfRecords=[self.SearchtableDataSource count];

    for (int i=0;i<TotalNoOfRecords;i++)
    {   NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.SearchtableDataSource objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"FirstName"];


        [searchArray addObject:array];


    }
    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    {

        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
        {
                [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];

        }
    }
```

How can i improve this code?....Please guide me... [searchArray release]; searchArray = nil;

How we maintain all the "Keys(FirstName,LastName,EmpCode)" in the searchArray please help me out? Thanks...

Comment: NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FirstName like[cd] %@",searchText]; NSArray* filteredArray = [self.SearchtableDataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; This is helpful for me but still i am not getting data after search. Please help me with some sample code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to make an array of `NSDictionary` which has value for three keys namely **"FirstName"**, **"LastName"**, **"EmpCode"**

now to filter the data according to "FirstName" use NSPredicate instead of for loop,

```
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FirstName like[cd] %@",searchText];
NSArray* filteredArray = [self.SearchtableDataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

In method cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
NSDictionary* currentEmp = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:inddexPath.row];
```

display the information in this currentEmp.

Similarly in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSDictionary* currentEmp = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:inddexPath.row];
```

and pass this dictionary in the next ViewController in which u want to dispaly the detail of the current employ.

if u have two table views one that of `searchDisplayController` (showing the filtered result)
and one which is showing the whole result, then u can track this by having a BOOL variable tacking that is if filtering is active or not.

Comment: Hi Amit.. Thank you for you... answer. I will try this approach. I think it will help me out to resolve the problem. No i am having only one UITabbleView. I would appreciate if you can give me dummy example like. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Amit please provide me few more tips for this i am very new developer in iPhone-Objective-c programming..Thank you..

Comment: NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FirstName like[cd] %@",searchText]; NSArray* filteredArray = [self.SearchtableDataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; This is helpful for me but still i am not getting data after search. Please help me with some sample code. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Amit Thanks for such a nice solution.. This is little modification according to ... NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText]; Which is working fine for me..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have done and its working fine with me(tested it). I have taken one IBOutlet of UISearchBar so here is the code for ur .h file

```
@interface SearchForEmp : UIViewController<'UISearchDisplayDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {

IBOutlet UISearchBar* mySearchBar;
UISearchDisplayController* mySearchDisplayController;

NSMutableArray* allEmp;
NSMutableArray* filteredEmp;
BOOL isFilatering;
}
@end
```

Now in .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mySearchBar contentsController:self];
mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
mySearchDisplayController.delegate = self;

isFilatering = NO;
filteredEmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
allEmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *temp;
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    temp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirstName_%d",i],@"FirstName",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"LastName_%d",i],@"LastName",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000+i],@"EmpCode",nil];
    [allEmp addObject:temp];
}
}
```

for e.g purpose i have thake an array of 30 Dictionaries, each with a unique name.For table view data source and delegate .....

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

if (isFilatering) {
    return [filteredEmp count];
}
else {
    return [allEmp count];
}
return [allEmp count];

}




-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];
}

NSDictionary* temp;
if (isFilatering) {
    temp = [filteredEmp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else {
    temp = [allEmp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[temp objectForKey:@"FirstName"],[temp objectForKey:@"LastName"]];
return cell;
}
```

Now as far as searching is concerned here is what u need to do .......

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText

{

NSPredicate* predicate = [[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.FirstName contains %@",mySearchBar.text] retain];
filteredEmp = [[allEmp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] retain];

}

-(void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller

{

isFilatering = YES;

}

-(void) searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller

{

isFilatering = NO;

}
```

I hope that helps you understanding the things, dont forget to add retain in line
`filteredEmp    = [[allEmp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] retain];`

because method `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` is an accessor method and its retain count is handled by the NSArray so have access to the filtered array u need to pass a retain msg to it.

Comment: this code is not showing the result is u r not searching ....... if u want that just add a tableView in the outlet and link its datasource nad delegate to the files owner it will show all data because code for same is written here.

Comment: Hi Amit....Your previous post is working fine for me.. with few change in this line.   NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText];  Your New post is also nice I will try this also. Thank you very much...